# Running Windows 7 on weak hardware

Tags: windows-7, performance

I have a PC machine with a Pentium 4 and 2GB RAM.

Windows 7 is installed, but it runs very slowly.

Installation of Windows XP is not suitable as I need to use some software that works only on Windows 7.

What can I do to increase the performance?

I have already tried some advice given by Auslogics boostspeed which helped a little bit.

Comment: please watch the future quality of your posts - this is your third recent post that has been closed or put on hold.

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Properties > Advanced System Settings > Advance tab.
In the Performance section, click Settings and select:
Adjust for best performance

This should disable themes and a lot of animations that should make your experience bearable to some extent.